# Mouse cursor disappearing after running gnome-settings-daemon in OpenBox

Tags: fedora, gnome, openbox

I'm running Openbox 3.5.2 on Fedora 20. For extra comfort (font rendering, tap-to-click, ...), I used to let `gnome-settings-daemon` run in the background.

Now since upgrading to the F20 beta, my mouse cursor is disappearing right after executing `/usr/libexec/gnome-settings-daemon`. That is it *visually* disappears; I am still able to click on things. But the impact on usability is unbearable nonetheless.

At first I thought compton were at fault, which I installed fresh out of koji. But removing it from my autostart doesn't change things for the better. The mouse is just fine in Gnome itself. There's nothing suspicious in `.xsession-errors` as far as I can tell. I'm really out of ideas right now.

Relevant system info:

```
$ rpm -q openbox compton gnome-settings-daemon
openbox-3.5.2-2.fc20.x86_64
compton-0-0.3.20121218g75aec17.fc19.x86_64
gnome-settings-daemon-3.10.2-3.fc20.x86_64
$ uname -sr
Linux 3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64
```

The machine itself is a X121e Thinkpad with a E-450 APU, powered by the OSS radeon driver.

Comment: I experienced the same problem on Ubuntu 13.10 with Openbox 3.5.2-3 and gnome-settings-daemon 3.8.5-0ubuntu9. Your answer below solved it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After further investigation, [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1334401#p1334401) in the Arch forums revealed the answer. I used `dconf-editor` to navigate to `org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/cursor` and unticked the `active` setting. `gnome-settings-daemon` is behaving perfectly well now.

Comment: thank you for this; you could also use `$dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/cursor false` in case it's not possible to get a GUI (dconf-editor).

Answer (score 2):

Correction to IlMostro_7: It should be `dconf write /org/gnome/settings/daemon/plugins/cursor/active false`