# Cursor disappears after login on xubuntu

Tags: login, x-server, xubuntu

A friend of mine has moved to linux recently, but he has had an issue with locking his screen, and logging in. His cursor disappears, but it can still interact with the environment. He says that moving his mouse to the whiskers menu seems to bring it back up, but it's really annoying for him. Does anyone know how to fix this? He says the only way he can really guess where his cursor is is by using oneko.

Note: The cursor does in fact appear on startup, but only disappers when he locks the screen and logs in again.

Comment: Try this:
[http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105607/mouse-cursor-disappearing-after-running-gnome-settings-daemon-in-openbox][1]

Comment: @nomasteryoda Your solution did not seem to work, sadly. Keep in mind that he is useing xfce, in nature of Xubuntu.

Comment: Probably a graphics card driver bug. (It wouldn't be the weirdest I've seen.) Updating the driver to a more recent version or fiddling with some obscure options might help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in linuxmint. I would leave the computer long enough for it to go to sleep then the cursor would disappear. I fished around until found the power button and restarted it and cursor was back. I am new to linux and still trying to find my way around. I went to preferences and scrolled down and found screensaver opened it clicked the settings tab and turned off the sleep mode. Problem solved!

Answer (score -2):

No mention of Xubuntu/Xfce versions nor hardware so it's all a stab in the dark.

Clearly a look through the logs may help.

Seem to remember lots of issues with light locker and screen locking. Try disabling that for starters.

Comment: This is not an answer. It would be more suitable as a comment.

Comment: Please comment this instead of posting as awnser

Comment: Couldn't see how on the app..... ironically I can comment on this...